# How do I show that this statement is true?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If I have the matrices $A$ and $D$ where if $D$ satisfies $AD=I$ ($I$ is the identity matrix) then $D=A^{-1}$, how do I show this is true using matrix algebra? I wanted to just say that if $D=A^{-1}$, then $AA^{-1}=I$ is true, but I don't think that's what my professor is looking for. This doesn't have to be a very formal proof or anything, it's just an introductory course on linear algebra.

Comment: What's the definition of $A^{-1}$? Are matrices square?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $A^{-1}$ exists.
$$
AD = I\\
A^{-1}AD = A^{-1}I \\
ID = A^{-1}I \\
D = A^{-1}
$$

Comment: Thanks, this is actually what a classmate of mine said, and I think this is a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that $A,D$ are square matrices operating on a finite dimensional space.

To some extent, this is more about a functional relationship, rather than specifically about matrices. The element of matrices that I use is the fact that the $D$ above must be surjective.

Since $AD = I$, we have $\operatorname{rk} AD = n$. It follows that $\operatorname{rk} D \ge \operatorname{rk} AD = n$, and hence $\operatorname{rk} D =n$. In particular, $D$ is surjective, hence for all $y$, there exists an $x$ such that $y=Dx$.

Let $\alpha(x) = Ax$, $\delta(x) = Dx$. We have $\alpha \circ \delta = \operatorname{Id}$, and hence $(\delta \circ \alpha) \delta(x) = \delta(x)$ for all $x$. Since $\delta$ is surjective, it follows that $\delta \circ \alpha = \operatorname{Id}$, or, in other words, $DA = I$.

Hence $D$ is the inverse of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume the matrices you are working are square. We have that $AD = I \Rightarrow D$ is row-reducible to the identity, and $A = E_1...E_k$ is exactly that sequence of elementary matrix (row) operations. Then $E_1...E_nD = I \Rightarrow D = E_n^{-1}...E_1^{-1} = A^{-1}$. This actually shows you what the inverse is if you calculate it out.

Answer (score 1):

If $det A = 0$, no matrix $B$ can be found for which either $AB = I$ or $BA = I$.

Proof:

$I = AB$ implies $1= det(AB) = det(A)det(B)$, so that $det(A) \ne 0$.

Similarly, $I = BA$ implies $det(A) \ne 0$.

From this, we can establish the following theorem.

If $det(A) = \Delta \ne 0$, define:

$A^{-1} = \Delta^{-1}(cof A)^{T}$.

Then, $AB = I$ if and only if $B = A^{-1}$. Similarly, $BA = I$ if and only if $B = A^{-1}$. Every equation $Ax = b$ has unique solution $x = A^{-1}b$.

Proof:
We know that $A^{-1}A = AA^{-1} = I$. Conversely, suppose $AB = I$ for some matrix $B$. Multiply both sides by $A^{-1}$ on the left, then: $(BA)A^{-1} = (I)A^{-1}$, or $BI = A^{-1}$, or $B = A^{-1}$.

If $BA = I$, multiply both sides by $A^{-1}$ on the right, then:

($BA)A^{-1} = (I)A^{-1}$, or $BI = A^{-1}$, or $B = A^{-1}$.

Comment: Nice proof! Well done, Amzoti!

Comment: My pleasure - you put a lot of time, thought, and effort into your answers, and MSE is all the richer for it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

(I assume all matrices involved are square and of the same dimension)

The definition of $A^{-1}$, when it exists, is that it is the unique solution to the system of equations

$$ AX = I \qquad \qquad XA = I $$

- Exercise: If $A^{-1}$ exists, then it is the **only** solution to $AX=I$

So to show that $D = A^{-1}$, one method is to prove both $AD=I$ and $DA=I$. In your case, the proof that $DA=I$ is 'tricky'; in general algebraic contexts one cannot make this inference! Determinants are useful here, as they give a convenient criteria for whether or not $A^{-1}$ even exists.